# Помогите перевести 2 строки конфига apache2 в nginx

Tags: apache, сервер, nginx, apache2

Сразу говорю, интернетом пользовался. Конвертеры не помагают.
Вот строки:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)v[0-9.]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg)$ /$1$2 [L,E=VERSIONED_FILE:1]
Header set "Expires" "Mon, 28 Jul 2020 23:30:00 GMT" env=VERSIONED_FILE
Header set "Cache-Control" "max-age=1427520746" env=VERSIONED_FILE
```

Их нужно запихнуть в кофиг nginx. Собственно строки нужны для жесткого кэширования. За раннее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если переменные окружения нужны только для этой логики HTTP заголовков, то можно без них обойтись, просто запихнув все во вложенный locaiton:

```
location ~* ^(.*\.)v[0-9.]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg)$ {
  rewrite ^(.*\.)v[0-9.]+\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg)$ /$1$2 break;
  expires  max;
  add_header Cache-Control public, max-age=1427520746;
  root /var/www/site/statica/;
}
```

Не проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта инструкция

```
expires  max;
```

заставит Nginx установить заголовок [Cache-control](http://highload.com.ua/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+Cache-control+%D0%B2+Nginx%3F), ее не нужно дополнительно добавлять.